# Date is not saving properly in mysql with NodeJS (one day lesser than real date)

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, date, express

I have created rest server using Node.JS and ExpressJS. Database is MySQL.
I'm passing date as follows from the frontend.

> 2016-7-26

And when I go to the database,it's saved like this. As the following :

> 2016-07-26 00:00:00

Because mysql date format is timestamp. And when I take the result from REST ruls, I get a date like this.

> "2016-07-25T18:30:00.000Z"

I saved 26. But here I get 25. What's the reason for this ? Timezones ? Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like the timezone issue.

Comment: This is a time-zone issue. Set your database to UTC unless you want to be battling this constantly. Use time-zones only in your application code, and even then only based on a user preference.

Comment: You mean change database time zone to UTC ? Did that. Not working

Comment: @tadman hey, i did that. not working still. can u plz help me

Comment: "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html maybe this could be an issue

Answer (score 7):

Issue is not with saving data or SQL itself; because if you directly run a query on DB it will show the correct value as saved.

You can fix this in each query by adding a date as some answers suggest, on the SQL side; but that won't be a correct solution.

Another option will be to fix this in node.js by adding value; which is not the right way too.

As per my understanding, **the right way to do this by setting the timezone when initializing the mysql connection.**

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.99.99.99',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydb',
    timezone: 'utc' //<-- here
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because node converts the date to ISOString and the date is in GMT.
Use `<your date>.toLocaleString();` after you query the data from the db.

Example:

```js
connection.query(yourDbQuery, function(err, result){ 
    if(result) {  
        var date = result.date.toLocaleString(); 
    }
});
```

Also you can install the npm moment which is very helpful with dates.

to install, use

`npm install moment`

and use the following code:

```js
const moment = require('moment');
let date = moment(result.date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: result.date = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY');  -> What's this code ?

Comment: I've edited the above.
the result is the result from the db query.
result.date assuming to be your date from db, 
you can also use this line instead of result.date.toLocaleString();

Comment: chanu1993@gmail.com -> email me

Answer (score 4):

By setting the connection options as

dateStrings: ['DATE','DATETIME']

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, .toLocalString() return the same iSOString format. So, I'm using my own coaded function to convert iSOString time to any format (In this case, UTC format).

ex.: 2018-02-09T12:18:23.000Z **=>** 2018-02-09 12:18:23

Here is how I'm getting UTC Date Format :

```
var date = date_formate(new Date(result[0].date), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Include below custom function in your code.

```
function date_formate (date, format, utc) {
    var MMMM = ["\x00", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var MMM = ["\x01", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var dddd = ["\x02", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var ddd = ["\x03", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    var y = utc ? date.getUTCFullYear() : date.getFullYear();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])yyyy+/g, "$1" + y);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])yy/g, "$1" + y.toString().substr(2, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])y/g, "$1" + y);

    var M = (utc ? date.getUTCMonth() : date.getMonth()) + 1;
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])MMMM+/g, "$1" + MMMM[0]);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])MMM/g, "$1" + MMM[0]);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])MM/g, "$1" + this.pad(M, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])M/g, "$1" + M);

    var d = utc ? date.getUTCDate() : date.getDate();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])dddd+/g, "$1" + dddd[0]);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])ddd/g, "$1" + ddd[0]);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])dd/g, "$1" + this.pad(d, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])d/g, "$1" + d);

    var H = utc ? date.getUTCHours() : date.getHours();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])HH+/g, "$1" + this.pad(H, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])H/g, "$1" + H);

    var h = H > 12 ? H - 12 : H == 0 ? 12 : H;
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])hh+/g, "$1" + this.pad(h, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])h/g, "$1" + h);

    var m = utc ? date.getUTCMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])mm+/g, "$1" + this.pad(m, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])m/g, "$1" + m);

    var s = utc ? date.getUTCSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])ss+/g, "$1" + this.pad(s, 2));
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])s/g, "$1" + s);

    var f = utc ? date.getUTCMilliseconds() : date.getMilliseconds();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])fff+/g, "$1" + this.pad(f, 3));
    f = Math.round(f / 10);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])ff/g, "$1" + this.pad(f, 2));
    f = Math.round(f / 10);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])f/g, "$1" + f);

    var T = H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])TT+/g, "$1" + T);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])T/g, "$1" + T.charAt(0));

    var t = T.toLowerCase();
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])tt+/g, "$1" + t);
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])t/g, "$1" + t.charAt(0));

    var tz = -date.getTimezoneOffset();
    var K = utc || !tz ? "Z" : tz > 0 ? "+" : "-";
    if (!utc) {
        tz = Math.abs(tz);
        var tzHrs = Math.floor(tz / 60);
        var tzMin = tz % 60;
        K += this.pad(tzHrs, 2) + ":" + this.pad(tzMin, 2);
    }
    format = format.replace(/(^|[^\\])K/g, "$1" + K);

    var day = (utc ? date.getUTCDay() : date.getDay()) + 1;
    format = format.replace(new RegExp(dddd[0], "g"), dddd[day]);
    format = format.replace(new RegExp(ddd[0], "g"), ddd[day]);

    format = format.replace(new RegExp(MMMM[0], "g"), MMMM[M]);
    format = format.replace(new RegExp(MMM[0], "g"), MMM[M]);

    format = format.replace(/\\(.)/g, "$1");

    return format;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its caused because JS is going to update any dates based on client time zone.
So, I used below npm library to update any Date objects those come from APIs and those come from SQL like below:

```
import { framework, libs } from 'saffroncodejs';//For react
import { framework, libs } from 'saffroncodejs-pure';//For NodeJS

...
//result.data.result = {any:1,item:2,haveDates:{any:2,date:"2016-07-25T18:30:00.000Z"}}

libs.JSFunctions.correctDates(result.data.result);

//>> result.data.result = {any:1,item:2,haveDates:{any:2,date:"2016-07-26T00:00:00.000Z"}}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/saffroncodejs

There you can find pure js script:
https://github.com/SaffronCode/SaffronCodeJS/blob/master/src/libs/JSFunctions.ts

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue but while fetching data from db. The date was shifting one day back.
So, to fix this issue. I formatted date in query itself.

```
DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

For eg. :- Problem :

**Query :**
    select percentage, DATE(date_time) as date from tbl;

Output :

```
[{
   percentage: 3,
   date: "2019-06-11T18:30:00.000Z"
 }]
```

Solution :

**Query:** 
    select percentage, DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d") as date from tbl;
Output:

```
[{
   percentage: 3,
   date: "2019-06-12"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, original date: 1/1/2020, db output: 12/31/2019.
This simple trick worked

```
var date = 'result from mysql';
date = date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
console.log(date); // 1/1/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Using moment helped me out in order to use it install moment to your project

```
npm install moment
```

now add this in your js file

```
const moment = require("moment");
moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
```

now you can get the exact date as you entered into your DB